# java android sqlite create table

Tags: java, android

I see that I create this table :

```
  db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE photos_name (" +
                "id integer primary key , " +
                "realize_id id, " +
                "name text " +
                ");"
        );
```

And I see that I did mistake realize_id should be integer , but it is work , Could you say me why ?

When I did this :

```
String[] columns = {"id", "realize_id", "name"};
    String selection = "realize_id" + "='" + realizeId + "'";
    net.sqlcipher.Cursor toDo = null;
     try {
                toDo = db.query("photos_name", columns, selection, null, null, null, null);
                if (toDo != null && toDo.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        PhotoPath photoPath = new PhotoPath();
                        photoPath.setId(toDo.getLong(0));
                        photoPath.setRealizeId(toDo.getLong(1));
                        photoPath.setPath(toDo.getString(2));
                        photoPaths.add(photoPath);
                    } while (toDo.moveToNext());
                }
            }
```

I have a value into realize_id, what type of valu I have on realize_id

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question. ? it is not much clear on the what is the requirement and what you have done already.

Comment: I think realize_id it is integer but your question it is very unclear what are you excepting.

Comment: @Spritzig I want to know what type data is a realize_id ?

Comment: @smilyface want to know what type data is a realize_id ?

Comment: @tompok It is integer.

Comment: @Spritzig but could you say me why ?

Comment: Because you set realize_id from id when you create the SQLite DB.